# Redirect to raw socket with iptables TPROXY

Tags: c, linux, iptables, raw-sockets

I intend using iptables' TPROXY target to redirect some UDP packets to
a raw socket, but no packet would received by socket.  It work with UDP
sockets.  Am I missing something or raw socket cannot receive data in
level TPROXY works?

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t mangle -p udp --dport 8816 --dst 127.0.0.1 -j
TPROXY --on-port 0 --on-ip 127.0.0.2
```

Code for consuming redirected packets:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char _errstr[100];
#define CHECK(X) \
if (! (X)) {\
    sprintf(_errstr, "%d: check failed", __LINE__);\
    perror(_errstr);\
    exit(1);\
}

int main() {
    int r;
    int fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_UDP);
    CHECK(fd != 0);
    int val = 1;
    CHECK(setsockopt(fd, SOL_IP, IP_TRANSPARENT, &val, sizeof(val))== 0);
    char buff[1500] = {0};

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.2");
    r = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr* )&addr, sizeof(addr));
    CHECK(r == 0);

    r = read(fd, buff, 1500);
    CHECK(r >= 0);

    int c;
    for (c=0; r>c; c++)
        printf("%02X ", 0xFF & *(buff + c));

    return 0;
}
```

I tested with netcat (nc -u 127.0.0.1 8816) and saw IPTables rule
matches but no packet sent to raw socket.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here `r = bind(fd, (struct sockaddr* )&addr, sizeof(addr));`. You should not `bind` to a raw socket, instead you should call `setsockopt` with `SO_BINDTODEVICE` to bind to the interface, in your case, it's the interface that has the address `127.0.0.2`.

For the details of how to use this option, check out http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket

Comment: Thanks. I replaced bind call with `setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, devname, strlen(devname))` and still no packet will come to raw socket. Note that redirecting packets to another IP (127.0.0.1) is not what I strictly need; I just wanted to make sure packet being redirected to a known to me IP. I skipped redirecting to 127.0.0.2 and still cannot get packet provided "127.0.0.1" to bind while It will work when I remove redirect IPtables rule.

Comment: @0x2c52 If you lunch `tcpdump` on the interface, do you see the proxy'ed packet show up?

Comment: @0x2c52 if tcpdump does not capture the packet, I think it means the proxy failed